# Systematic Pricing and Trading of Municipal Bonds by P. Kolm

Tags: fixed-income

does anyone have the pdf for this article? It was available on SSRN a few weeks ago but not anymore, I'd really appreciate it if someone could share it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I see that [Prof. Petter Kolm](https://math.nyu.edu/people/profiles/KOLM_Petter.html)'s article has been published in the *Journal of Financial Data Science* https://jfds.pm-research.com/content/early/2021/11/24/jfds.2021.1.079 - there appears to be a paywall there.

SSRN https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3899133 says "Not available for download"

I suggest that you e-mail the author at first.last@nyu.edu and ask.

Comment: /sarcasm These journals do a great job of preventing the spread of scientific and technical knowledge /end_sarcasm

Comment: That's a whole big separate debate. I do wish people would simply not submit papers to journals that require pulling preprints from arxiv/ssrn. There are enough other choices.